# Paperclip upload / update: Getting can't modify frozen String: "" error on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

On Rails 6.0.3.3 and ruby 2.7.0, using kt-paperclip (~> 6.3)

This is the content of my View:

```
<%= form_for brand, url: brand_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
<% end %>
```

This is the content of my Model:

```
    has_attached_file :logo,
                      styles:      { medium: "300x300>" },
                      default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

   validates_attachment_content_type :logo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

This is the content of my Controller:

```
def update
  brand.update! brand_params
  [...]
end

def brand_params
  @brand_params ||= params.require(:brand).permit(:logo)
end
```

Getting a "can't modify frozen String: """ on `brand.update!` when I try to upload or update a picture.

Trace show this (from httplog (1.4.3) lib/httplog/http_log.rb) :

```
def utf_encoded(data, content_type = nil)

  charset = content_type.to_s.scan(/; charset=(\S+)/).flatten.first || 'UTF-8'

  begin

    data.force_encoding(charset)

  rescue StandardError

    >>> data.force_encoding('UTF-8')

  end

  data.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)

end

def text_based?(content_type)
```

Comment: Seems like `data` is a frozen string. And that's probably the reason why `data.force_encoding(charset)` failed in the first place – you can't change a frozen string, including its encoding.

Comment: Yeah, this code is actually from lib/httplog/http_log.rb (https://github.com/trusche/httplog) and I saw a PR about this specific error. Thank you for the lead!